# Load data to Salesforce using COPY INTO

Tags: csv, copy, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have been trying to load csv data into Snowflake using COPY INTO command

This is the sample data
`4513194677~"DELL - ULTRASHARP 32\" MONITOR 4K U3223QE"~""~""`

I have tried using below COPY INTO syntax

```
            file_format = 
            type = 'csv' 
            field_delimiter = '~'
            skip_header = 1 
            record_delimiter = '\\n' 
            field_optionally_enclosed_by = '"' 
            ESCAPE = 'NONE'
            ESCAPE_UNENCLOSED_FIELD = 'NONE'
```

However, getting this error "Found character 'M' instead of field delimiter '~'"

How can I escape the " and load the columns data as **DELL - ULTRASHARP 32 " MONITOR 4K U3223QE**

If I try to use ESCAPE, I get below error when running the COPY command
[ERROR] ProgrammingError: 001003 (42000): 01a8e01d-3201-36a9-0050-4502537cfc7f: SQL compilation error:
syntax error line 15 at position 43 unexpected '''.
syntax error line 20 at position 20 unexpected ')'.

```
            file_format = 
            type = 'csv' 
            field_delimiter = '~'
            skip_header = 1 
            record_delimiter = '\\n' 
            field_optionally_enclosed_by = '"' 
            ESCAPE = '\\'
            ESCAPE_UNENCLOSED_FIELD = '\\'
```

Comment: The file format in your second example is correct, based on what you are planning to do. However, there is a syntax error which suggest that in your command you might use  just one backslash, which is default escape character in SQL as well. Can you check your COPY INTO command and if there is just one backslash for "ESCAPE" and "ESCAPE_UNENCLOSED_FIELD" replace them as `ESCAPE = '\\' ESCAPE_UNENCLOSED_FIELD = '\\'`

Answer (score 0):

Try using two double quotes in the data instead of one without trying to escape the double quote

```
Data similar to "sample"
```

You can have your csv formated like below

```
"Data similar to ""sample"""
```